# Why Array of Pointer and Array giving same output

Tags: c

1)
  How to access array element with array of pointers?

By pointer to an array we can access like this (∗a)[0]
,(∗a)[22]
,….. like this

right?

but how with array of pointer?

2)
Check these three codes , one of them use array and one of them use array of pointer, and 3rd one using double pointer, but all giving same output. Why??

```
#include <stdio.h>
int ptr[12];
int main(void) {
if(*(ptr+5)==*(ptr+3)){
printf("Equal");
}
else{
printf("Not Equal");
}
return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
int *ptr[12];
int main(void) {
if(*(ptr+5)==*(ptr+3)){
printf("Equal");
}
else{
printf("Not Equal");
}
return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int **ptr[12];
    int main(void) {
    if(*(ptr+5)==*(ptr+3)){
    printf("Equal");
    }
    else{
    printf("Not Equal");
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `*(ptr + 5)` is exactly equivalent with `ptr[5]`, period. Your arrays are zero-initialized. All array elements are zeroes / null pointers. Therefore they all are equal to each other. What there is to wonder about?!

Comment: But last two codes we are initialized array of pointer and array of pointer of a pointer. Then what will be value of array, as we never initialize the array, but the pointer

Comment: There are 3 arrays: one where each element is an int, each initialized to zero, one where each element is a pointer to int, **each element** initialized to null pointer. And one where each element is a pointer to pointer to int, **each element** initialized to null pointer.

Comment: Srestha is correct: you are comparing the *value* of the pointed-to objects, which are zero-initialized and never changed.  Assign some values before comparing to see.
  
The *addresses* of the pointed-to objects (ie, the values of the pointers themselves) will not be the same... normally I'd rewrite that comparison as `&ptr[5] == &ptr[3]`, but rewriting it with the syntax you used, `&*(ptr+5) == &*(ptr+3)` is actually instructive here.  Since adding `&` is the solution and `&*` cancels out by definition, hopefully that illustrates how dereferencing was the error in the first place.

Comment: @ Antti Haapala, u mean as each element of array is 0, so any pointer to that array is NULL pointer? But 0 does not mean NULL always. Right?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala,@l.k Please tell me, here we also do not know array size. Then how do we know , if *(ptr+5)==*(ptr+3) exists for int *ptr[12] or not, and How do we even know if this for an array, because in 2nd program we initialised a pointer and not an array. right??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `*(ptr+5)`:

- `ptr` is the name of an array.
- When an array is used in an expression and is not the operand of `sizeof` or unary `&` and is not a string literal used to initialize an array, it is converted to a pointer to its first element. So `ptr` points to element 0 of the array.
- `ptr+5` adds five, resulting in a pointer to element 5 of the array.
- `*` dereferences the pointer, producing the contents of element 5 of the array.

Since the array is defined outside any function, it is initialized to zero. Therefore element 5 is zero, so `*(ptr+5)` is zero. Similarly, `*(ptr+3)` is zero, so comparing them shows they are equal.

The examples with `int ptr[12];`, `int *ptr[12];`, and `int **ptr[12];` just change the types of the elements in the array. In each case `*(ptr+5)` and `*(ptr+3)` refer to elements 5 and 3 of the array. In each case, the values of the elements are zero (null pointers for the pointer types).

If you want to see differences between different elements of the array, then assign different values to the elements of the array.

Comment: Well you too could point out that `*(ptr + 5)` ===== `ptr[5]`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  Please tell me, here we also do not know array size. Then how do we know , if *(ptr+5)==*(ptr+3) exists for int *ptr[12] or not, and How do we even know if this for an array, because in 2nd program we initialised a pointer and not an array. right?

Comment: @Srestha: No, the second program does not have an array instead of a pointer. `int *ptr[12]` is an array of 12 pointers to `int`. It is not a pointer. A pointer to an array of 12 `int` would be `int (*ptr)[12]`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil then how it is comparing array element exists or not?? I mean how it checks "(ptr+5)==*(ptr+3)" as equal????

Comment: @Srestha: `*(ptr+5)` is the value of element 5 of the array. It is zero. `*(ptr+3)` is the value of element 3 of the array. It is zero. Zero equals zero.

Comment: @EricPostpischil array element will be zero. That is ok. But where we declared array in 2nd and 3rd program, those are array of pointer. That was my question

Comment: @EricPostpischil pointer is NULL, that means it is not pointing any location

Does it not mean *(ptr+5),*(ptr+3) place of array not addressed by any pointer. So, *(ptr+5),*(ptr+3) can contain garbage value??

Comment: `int *ptr[12]` is an array of 12 pointers to `int`. When it is zero-initialized, all of the pointers in the array are `NULL`.  `*(ptr+5)` is element 5 of the array. It is `NULL`. `*(ptr+3)` is element 3 of the array. It is `NULL`. `NULL` equals `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just keep incrementing the pointer as you go along reading the array. Analyze the 
   code below:

   ```
     #include <stdio.h>
     int main(void) {
       int *ptr[3];
       int a[] = { 0,1,2};
       int b[] = { 3,4,5 };
       int c[] = { 6,7,8 };
       ptr[0] = a;
       ptr[1] = b;
       ptr[2] = c;
       for (int i = 0;i < 3;i++)
       printf("%d %d %d\n",*ptr[0]++,*ptr[1]++,*ptr[2]++);
       return 0;
    }
   ```

   2. Answered in comments.